# Scipy mmread for matrix array real general

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a simple matrix

```
%%MatrixMarket matrix array real general
%blah
2 2
3 2
2 2
```

I try to read this

```
from scipy.io import mmread
test = mmread('test.mm')
```

I get

```
<type 'exceptions.ValueError'> invalid literal for float(): 3 2
```

However if I have single column, things are fine

```
%%MatrixMarket matrix array real general
%blah
2 1
3 
2
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `array` format requires the entries to be given on separate lines, in column-major order.  That is, if the matrix is M x N, then the first M values are the first column, the next M are the second column, etc.

For example, the array

```
[11  12]
[21  22]
```

would be

```
%%MatrixMarket matrix array real general
%blah
2 2
11
21
12
22
```